# Is there a way to encode all decimal numbers between 0 and 1 into whole numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Is there a way to encode ALL decimal numbers between 0 and 1 into whole numbers with a rationale that supports sum operations between the encoded numbers?

so
1=0.1
2=0.2
3=0.3...

1+2 = 3 .. 0.2+0.1 = 0.3 .. 3 = 0.3

But in way that we could theoretically include ALL decimal numbers between 0 and 1 and it still works

Comment: This question could be made more interesting by instead of considering all real numbers between $0$ and $1$, to consider only the rational numbers between $0$ and $1$.  Even this will encounter issues however, but not in the fact that the set sizes are different, but rather in trying to have the summation property hold how you like.

Comment: Rational numbers will be interesting.  If we have x-> n then we must have $(1/2)^mx$ -> $(1/2)^mn$ which is impossible for non-zero integers.  But not imposible for rationals.

Comment: @JMoravitz to preserve sumation if 1->z, and q is rational q->qz.  So we might as well map the rationals to themselves.  How to map the irrationals.  we need x->q then p-x -> p-q, which I think will be impossible.  There must be uncountably "unrelated" irrationals that map to the same rational and addition will not be consistent, I think.

Comment: @fleablood I think perhaps you read my comment backwards, I mean mapping rational to natural numbers, preserving addition.  I did not mean mapping real numbers to rationals (which has the same issue of cardinality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There are an uncountable number
of real numbers between
0 and 1
and there are only
a countable number of whole numbers.

Comment: The mapping doesn't have to be (can not be) one to one.  Encoding them all to zero will be a successful way to do this.  Don't know if there are any nonn-trivial ways.

Comment: Right, different kinds of infinity. Back to apples and oranges for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Encode them all to 0.

There is no other way.  If $x \ne 0$ maps to $n \ne 0$ then $1/2 x$ must map to $1/2 n$ (so $1/2*x + 1/2*x$ maps to $1/2*n + 1/2*n$).  So $(1/2)^m x$ must map to $(1/2)^m n$ for all $m$ but $(1/2)^m * n$ can't all be whole numbers.